# Reading debug registers on linux

Tags: c, linux, assembly

I would like to detect hardware breakpoints. I am able to read the register values using:

```
unsigned sp;
__asm __volatile("movl %%esp, %0" : "=r" (sp));
return sp;
```

Trying to read `dr0` on a 64 machine I get `Error: unsupported instruction 'mov'`.
I managed to compile with `-m32`, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to run.

How can I check the debug registers? I am interested in both 32 and 64 bit solutions.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Please explain.

Comment: You are downvoted because you didn't show us the faulty code. How are we supposed to tell you what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did?

Comment: @FUZxxl, the faulty code is above, just replace esp with dr0.

Comment: If you would have said that in the first place, there wouldn't have been any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a 64 bit register in 64 bit mode, that's why it doesn't compile (presumably, since you have not showed the actual code you tried...)

In any case, you can't read debug registers in user mode. You should say why you need access to them otherwise it's an XY problem. My best guess is that you might be interested in the `ptrace` API instead.

Comment: Edited, I would like to detect if there are hardware breakpoints set. And there is everything, I changed `esp` to `dr0`, and tried to print the value.

Comment: @franz1  I don't think you can do that on Linux. Accessing the debug registers is a privileged operation and you the operating system doesn't allow you to do that. Instead, use the `ptrace()` API to find out if you are being debugged.

Comment: Also note that calling `ptrace` will fail if somebody else is already attached, which is an indication already. And if the debugger is clever enough to hide itself, it will also do so for the debug registers.